# Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'AST' must be declared in Package

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c, pls-00201

I am getting error while running below code. I have already created a type but still getting an Error:

> PLS-00201: identifier 'AST' must be declared

Please help me to resolve the error in *ORACLE 12C*.

*TYPE CREATION :*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "AST" AS VARRAY(255) OF varchar2(100);
```

*PACKAGE CREATION :*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC IS

  FUNCTION F_PRODUCT_NAME(P_ATTRIBUTE_UA_NAME IN PRODUCT.Attribute_Ua_Name%TYPE)
    RETURN AST;

END ABC;
```

Answer (score 1):

> The Problem is not related to your `Type Definition`, provided that the type name is exactly specified as `AST` [ without quotes ] or `"AST"` [ inside quotes but all in upper-case letters ]

If you have a *table* or *view* called `Product`, and that has a column called `Attribute_Ua_Name` in your *current* schema, there will no error raise.

***BUT*** It seems that the problem is due to the definition of the Type `AST` inside quotes but not in all upper-case such as `"AsT"` or `"aST"` etc. Here's the testing case for this error

( Assume in this case that table `Product` exists and has a column called `Attribute_Ua_Name` ):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "AsT" AS VARRAY(255) OF varchar2(100);
  2  /

Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC IS
  2    FUNCTION F_PRODUCT_NAME(P_ATTRIBUTE_UA_NAME IN PRODUCT.Attribute_Ua_Name%TYPE) RETURN AST;
  3  END ABC;
  4  /

Warning: Package created with compilation errors

SQL> show err;
Errors for PACKAGE MYSCHEMA.ABC:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------
2/89     PLS-00201: identifier 'AST' must be declared
2/3      PL/SQL: Declaration ignored

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "AST" AS VARRAY(255) OF varchar2(100);
  2  /

Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC IS
  2    FUNCTION F_PRODUCT_NAME(P_ATTRIBUTE_UA_NAME IN PRODUCT.Attribute_Ua_Name%TYPE) RETURN AST;
  3  END ABC;
  4  /

Package created
```

Comment: If the problem is with the product table, why does the error refer to AST?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, exactly you're right Alex, thank you. I suspected then but I missed that part because of the all-Upper Case`'AST'` in the explanation of `PLS-00201` +1

Comment: Thanks all.. I have done the change and made in upper case. but still getting the error. I have created type in ARCH scema and executing the package in INV_TEMP scema.  TYPE CREATION :

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ARCH.AST AS VARRAY(255) OF varchar2(100);CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC IS

  FUNCTION F_PRODUCT_NAME(P_ATTRIBUTE_UA_NAME IN PRODUCT.Attribute_Ua_Name%TYPE)
    RETURN ARCH.AST;

END ABC;

Answer (score 1):

What you have works fine, assuming you actually did create the type in the same schema as the table and package;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "AST" AS VARRAY(255) OF varchar2(100)
/

Type AST compiled

create table PRODUCT(Attribute_Ua_Name varchar2(30))
/

Table PRODUCT created.

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC IS

  FUNCTION F_PRODUCT_NAME(P_ATTRIBUTE_UA_NAME IN PRODUCT.Attribute_Ua_Name%TYPE)
    RETURN AST;

END ABC;
/

Package ABC compiled

show errors

No errors.
```

If you get "PLS-00201: identifier 'AST' must be declared" then you either didn't actually run that statement, or you ran it in a different schema. If it is in a different schema then you can just prefix it with the owning schema name

```
  FUNCTION F_PRODUCT_NAME(P_ATTRIBUTE_UA_NAME IN PRODUCT.Attribute_Ua_Name%TYPE)
    RETURN owning_schema.AST;
```

> I have created a package and table in same schema (ARCH) and type is created in different schema (INV_TEMP).

Then from your `INV_TEMP` schema you need to:

```
grant execute on AST to ARCH;
```

and the function definition needs to refer to the type owner in the package specification in the `ARCH` schema:

```
  FUNCTION F_PRODUCT_NAME(P_ATTRIBUTE_UA_NAME IN PRODUCT.Attribute_Ua_Name%TYPE)
    RETURN INV_TEMP.AST;
```

When you write the package body the function will also have to refer to the `INV_TEMP` owner, both in the definition (to match the specification) and when declaring an `INV_TEMP.AST` object variable or creating an object as part of a query.

Comment: I have created a package and table in same schema (ARCH) and type is created in different schema (INV_TEMP).

Comment: @DeepakPatil - OK, then the function return should be `RETURN INV_TEMP.AST`. But as that user you might also need to `grant execute on AST to ARCH`.